# Running two VBA codes on same Excel breaks

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using VBA in Access to modify a excel sheet using Macro 1 and input it in a table using Macro 2. When I run both of these consecutively, my system gets stuck in a loop, but works fine if I restart the Microsoft access application after running one Macro and run Macro 2. Also at times, the excel file on which I am running my code gets a pop-up box to enable read/write access.. Can someone help me with it?

Macro1

```
Function Clean()


Dim CurrFilePath, PathName, Week As String
Dim Filename
Dim OpenExcel As Object
Set OpenExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
OpenExcel.Visible = False
Dim OpenWorkbook, WS As Object
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim Count_WS As Integer
OpenExcel.Quit
CurrFilePath = Application.CurrentProject.path
StartTime = Timer

Week = InputBox("Enter the week for the data import e.g. 34")
PathName = CurrFilePath & "\Direct Deliveries\Week " & Week & "\"
Example = CurrFilePath & "\Direct Deliveries\Week " & Week
Confirm:
    Confirm_Folder = MsgBox("Does the Direct Deliveries info exist in " & PathName & " path", vbYesNo)
    If Confirm_Folder = vbNo Then
    path = InputBox("Locate Direct Deliveries .xlsx on your System and Copy the Dir path here e.g." & Example)
    PathName = path & "\"
    GoTo Confirm
    End If

Filename = Dir(PathName & "*.xlsx")



Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    Set OpenExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    OpenExcel.Visible = False
    OpenExcel.EnableEvents = False
    OpenExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Variables to track first cell
    i = 0
    j = 0
    PathFile = PathName & Filename
    Set OpenWorkbook = OpenExcel.Workbooks.Open(PathFile)

    For Each WS In OpenWorkbook.Worksheets
        'If condition to check correct worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        If Range("A1").Value = "Carrier SCAC" And Range("D1").Value = "Trip ID" Then

            'Loop to fill blank TripIDs
            For Each Cell In WS.UsedRange.Columns(4).Cells
                ' For blank cells, set them to equal the cell above
                If WS.Cells(Cell.Row, 1) <> "ABCD" And Not IsEmpty(WS.Cells(Cell.Row, 9)) Then
                        If i <> 0 Then
                            If (Len(Cell.Text) = 0) And PreviousCell <> "Trip ID" And Cell.Row Then
                                Cell.Value = PreviousCell
                            End If

                        End If
                        PreviousCell = Cell
                        i = i + 1
                End If
            Next Cell

            'Loop to fill blank SCAC Codes
            For Each CarrierCell In WS.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
                ' For blank cells, set them to equal the cell above
                If j <> 0 Then

                    If (Len(CarrierCell.Text) = 0) And PreviousCell <> "Carrier SCAC" And PreviousCell <> "ABCD" And Not IsEmpty(WS.Cells(CarrierCell.Row, 4)) Then
                        CarrierCell.Value = PreviousCell
                    End If

                End If
                PreviousCell = CarrierCell
                j = j + 1
            Next CarrierCell
        End If
        Count_WS = Count_WS + 1
    Next WS
    Filename = Dir()
    OpenWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set OpenWorkbook = Nothing
    OpenExcel.Quit
    Set OpenExcel = Nothing


Loop



'Display the end status
TotalTime = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
Application.Echo True

DeleteImportErrTables

End Function
```

Macro 2

```
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Author: Akanksha Goel
' The code imports Direct Deliveries erroneous excel templates to Access Database
'------------------------------------------------------------
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function ListErrBeforeImports()
Dim OpenExcel As Object
Set OpenExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
OpenExcel.Visible = False
Dim PathFile As String, Filename As String, PathName As String
Dim TableName As String
Dim HasFieldNames As Boolean
Dim OpenWorkbookED As Object
Dim SQL, CurrFilePath As String
Dim SQLcreate, SQLAlter, SQLSet As String
Dim SQL2, SQL3 As String
Dim Count_Templates As Integer

StartTime = Timer
OpenExcel.Quit


'Turn Off the warnings and screen updating
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Application.Echo False
OpenExcel.EnableEvents = False
OpenExcel.ScreenUpdating = False


CurrFilePath = Application.CurrentProject.path
Week = InputBox("Enter the week for the data import e.g. 34")
PathName = CurrFilePath & "\Direct Deliveries\Week " & Week & "\"
Example = CurrFilePath & "\Direct Deliveries\Week " & Week
Confirm:
    Confirm_Folder = MsgBox("Does the Direct Deliveries info exist in " & PathName & " path", vbYesNo)
    If Confirm_Folder = vbNo Then
    path = InputBox("Locate Direct Deliveries .xlsx on your System and Copy the Dir path here e.g." & Example)
    PathName = path & "\"
    GoTo Confirm
    End If

HasFieldNames = True


TableName = "TempTable"
Filename = Dir(PathName & "*.xlsx")
PathFile = PathName & Filename
'Arguments for function AssignTablesToGroup()
Dim Arg1 As String
Dim Arg2 As Integer
Arg1 = "EmptyDeliveryDates_TripsWeek" & Week
Call DeleteTable(Arg1)
Arg2 = 383
SQLcreate = "Create Table EmptyDeliveryDates_TripsWeek" & Week & " ( TripID Text, ShipToZip Text, ArriveDelivery Text, Carrier Text, SourceWorkbook Text);"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLcreate
'Assign Error Table to 'Errors in DirectDeliveries Excels' Group
Call AssignToGroup(Arg1, Arg2)

'Arguments for function AssignTablesToGroup()
Dim Arg3 As String
Arg3 = "InvalidZip_TripsWeek" & Week
DeleteTable Arg3
Arg2 = 383
SQLcreate = "Create Table InvalidZip_TripsWeek" & Week & " ( TripID Text, ShipToZip Text, ArriveDelivery Text, Carrier Text, SourceWorkbook Text);"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLcreate
'Assign Error Table to 'Errors in DirectDeliveries Excels' Group
Call AssignToGroup(Arg3, Arg2)

'Arguments for function AssignTablesToGroup()
Dim Arg4 As String
Arg4 = "InvalidTrip_TripsWeek" & Week
DeleteTable Arg4
Arg2 = 383
SQLcreate = "Create Table InvalidTrip_TripsWeek" & Week & " ( TripID Text, ShipToZip Text, ArriveDelivery Text, Carrier Text, SourceWorkbook Text);"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLcreate
'Assign Error Table to 'Errors in DirectDeliveries Excels' Group
Call AssignToGroup(Arg4, Arg2)



Do While Len(Filename) > 0
        Set OpenExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        OpenExcel.Visible = False
        OpenExcel.EnableEvents = False
        OpenExcel.ScreenUpdating = False

        PathFile = PathName & Filename
        Set OpenWorkbookED = OpenExcel.Workbooks.Open(PathFile, ReadOnly)
        Set WS_Book = OpenWorkbookED.Worksheets
        DeleteTable "TempTable"
        'Loop through Worksheets in each template workbook
        For Each WS In WS_Book
        WorksheetName = WS.Name
        x = WS.Range("A1")
            If WS.Range("A1") = "Carrier SCAC" Then
            'Get the used records in worksheet
                GetUsedRange = WS.UsedRange.Address(0, 0)
                'Import records from worksheet into Access Database table
                DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "TempTable", PathFile, HasFieldNames, WorksheetName & "!" & GetUsedRange
                SQLAlter = "ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD COLUMN SourceBook TEXT(100)"
                DoCmd.RunSQL SQLAlter
                SQLSet = "UPDATE TempTable SET TempTable.SourceBook = '" & Filename & "' where ([Arrive Delivery]) is NULL or len([Arrive Delivery])<2 or len([Trip ID])<8 or len([Ship to Zip])<5;"
                DoCmd.RunSQL SQLSet
                SQL = "INSERT INTO " & Arg4 & "(TripID, ShipToZip, ArriveDelivery, Carrier, SourceWorkbook) Select Distinct [Trip ID], [Ship to Zip], [Arrive Delivery], [Carrier SCAC], SourceBook FROM TempTable WHERE len([Trip ID])<8 and len([Ship To Zip])>0 and len([Arrive Delivery])>0;"
                DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
                SQL2 = "INSERT INTO " & Arg3 & "(TripID, ShipToZip, ArriveDelivery, Carrier, SourceWorkbook) Select Distinct [Trip ID], [Ship to Zip], [Arrive Delivery], [Carrier SCAC], SourceBook FROM TempTable WHERE len([Ship To Zip])<5 and len([Arrive Delivery])>0 and len([Trip ID])>0;"
                DoCmd.RunSQL SQL2
                SQL3 = "INSERT INTO " & Arg1 & "(TripID, ShipToZip, ArriveDelivery, Carrier, SourceWorkbook) Select Distinct [Trip ID], [Ship to Zip], [Arrive Delivery], [Carrier SCAC], SourceBook FROM TempTable WHERE ([Arrive Delivery] is NULL or len([Arrive Delivery])<2) and len([Ship To Zip])>0 and len([Trip ID])>0 ;"
                DoCmd.RunSQL SQL3
                DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "TempTable"
                Count_Templates = Count_Templates + 1
            End If


        Next WS

        OpenWorkbookED.Saved = True
        OpenWorkbookED.Close

        Filename = Dir()
        Set OpenWorkbookED = Nothing
        OpenExcel.Quit
        Set OpenExcel = Nothing


Loop


'Display the end status
TotalTime = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "Done! Error tables updated in 'Errors in DirectDeliveries Excels' group  in with " & Count_Templates & " Templates " & TotalTime & " minutes", vbInformation
Application.Echo True
'CallFunction Delete Import Tables
DeleteImportErrTables

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

*Merge* the two functions so you only open one instance (your `OpenExcel` object) of Excel.

Comment: As the second function is only run if the user wants to view the output for second, it is not reasonable to merge the function in the current use case.

Comment: Still, the solution is to reuse the already opened object. Alternatively, check for its existence before opening a new.